# Solr - The requested resource (/solr/suggest) is not available

Tags: solr

I followed this tutorial: http://solr.pl/en/2010/11/15/solr-and-autocomplete-part-2/

In the tutorial, it's said to send "/suggest?spellcheck.build=true" to solr, so I did this in the browser (I could be wrong here?)
    localhost:8080/solr/suggest?spellcheck.build=true
and then i got the error below:

```
HTTP Status 404 - /solr/suggest

type Status report

message /solr/suggest

description The requested resource (/solr/suggest) is not available.

Apache Tomcat/7.0.27
```

Anyone knows how to fix this? thanks for your help!

Comment: After I restarted tomcat, /suggest?spellcheck.build=true works, but it throws exception in the browser as:Java heap space java.lang.OutOfMemoryError. whatelse can i do?

Comment: I think i need to somehow increase the heap size, however how to do this in tomcat or jvm? Also, should i run spellcheck.build=true in the browser or command line using curl?

Comment: read the [oom](http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/OutOfMemory) to understand better. Depend your tomcat custom installation or packages from distribution, but you should be able to alter the heap in the tomcat config file, read [here](http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/Memory#Q1) to get an idea.

Answer (score 2):

Solr suggester is a component that might not be enabled by default.

Check if your **solrconfig.xml** has an active requestHandler with name "/suggest".

If not, follow the instructions in this Solr wiki page to activate it: [Suggester](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/Suggester)